# GCD Semaphore not working in IPC using shared memory

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore, mmap

I am trying to establish IPC using some shared memory. I used GCD's semaphores for accessing the memory. This is the minimal recreation of the problem I encountered:

```
/* A simple readers/writers program using a one-word shared memory. */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>          
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

dispatch_semaphore_t* mutex;

int main (void){  
  mutex = (dispatch_semaphore_t*)mmap(0, sizeof(dispatch_semaphore_t)*2, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);

  if(mutex == MAP_FAILED){
    printf("Error while mapping");
    exit(1);
  }
  
  *mutex = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
  *(mutex+1) = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
  pid_t pid;
  if((pid = fork()) < 0){
    printf("Error while creating child process\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if(pid){
    printf("Parent started\n");
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(*mutex, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    printf("Parent in crit section\n");
    // Crit
    printf("Parent exiting crit section\n");
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(*(mutex+1));
    wait(NULL);
  }
  else{
    printf("Child started\n");
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(*(mutex+1), DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    printf("Child in crit section\n");
    // Crit
    printf("Child exiting crit section\n");
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(*mutex);
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

The output I expect is that the parent would first enter and exit critical section and that the child would follow. But this is the output I get:

```
Parent started
Parent in crit section
Parent exiting crit section
Child started
```

The child process keeps waiting. Clearly, the parent process's `dispatch_semaphore_signal()` seems to not work.
I have found answers that use POSIX semaphores stored in shared memory for IPC but I couldn't find how to do this for GCD's dispatch semaphores.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can solve this? Please suggest a solution using GCD's dispatch semaphores not POSIX's named or unnamed semaphores. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using GCD, why are you using fork and not DispatchWorkItem?